# Looking for a lightweight ASP.net shopping cart that is PayPal compatible

Tags: asp.net, e-commerce, paypal

I am currently developing a simple eCommerce site.  I am looking for a lightweight non hosted ASP.net shopping cart solution that needs to

- Be able to talk to PayPal
- Integrate with current site
- Preferably handle PayPal's Instant Payment Notification

The current site uses PayPal buy it now buttons or PayPal's add to cart buttons.  The issue I have with PayPal's cart is that it allows buyers to update the quantities of items in their cart prior to checkout which is unacceptable because each item in this site is unique (i.e. quantity 1).

I wrote a handler for PayPal's Instant Payment Notification in order to remove an item from the site when it was sold but it is pretty inflexible and I don't have time or money to write a good one so something that handles that would be great :)

Anybody used any non hosted ASP paypal shopping carts before and have some recommendations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's always:

[Shopping Cart.NET](http://shoppingcartnet.codeplex.com/)

although this may or may not be as "lightweight" as you'd like.

Alternatively, [The Beerhouse](http://thebeerhouse.codeplex.com/) has an e-commerce "module" containing a shopping cart with PayPal integration, although "The Beerhouse" itself is a complete application, and you  would need to refactor out the shopping cart code for your own uses.  It is much more "lightweight", however.  (Note that the most recent release of The Beerhouse is for ASP.NET MVC whereas older releases are for WebForms).

Comment: Thank you for your response.  What I have found is that most shopping cart software out there is an entire Web Shop package.  Thanks for pointing out a couple more opensource solutions.  I think now that it is much better to use one of these solutions and not try to write your own ecommerce site.  Even a simple shop has lots of little complexities to consider.

Comment: I can't get Shopping Cart.Net to work. I will try http://www.spicelogic.com/Products/ASP-NET-PayPal-Control-for-Website-Payments-Standard-4 and report back to you

Answer (score 1):

You can always pick out parts of [Shopping Cart .NET](http://shoppingcartnet.codeplex.com) to use on your site. You can use InvertedSoftware.ShoppingCart.Intergration for PayPal and InvertedSoftware.ShoppingCart.BusinessLayer for the cart. I can point you in the right direction if you like since i wrote it.

Gal

Comment: Hi Gal, does the cart functionality work with a PayPal standard account, which passes all payment operations over to PayPal (with a set of items and prices) and then calls a url with an IPN to confirm successful transactions? If so could you please point me in that direction? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out nopCommerce:

http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/nopCommerce.aspx

Might not be exactly what you are after, but it's pretty good, open source and you can at least have a look at how they have done things.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Not exactly what I had in mind for this project.  Don't need the whole application suite just a cart that can talk with payPal.  But in the future I'll keep this in mind instead of trying to reinvent the wheel :).

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with building your shopping cart using a Control (for Web Form) or component (for ASP.NET MVC), then, you may try the ASP.NET PayPal Control for Website Payments Standard.

Here is the link : http://www.spicelogic.com/Products/ASP-NET-PayPal-Control-for-Website-Payments-Standard-4

The download also contains sample projects for paypal payment gateway integration in asp net MVC and web form.

Answer (score -1):

We haven't released yet, but if you have patient deadlines, consider DotNetMerchant (http://dotnetmerchant.org), it's a library you can add to your solution to call multiple payment processors, and we will support PayPal (Website Payments Pro, PayFlow Pro, and IPN)

Comment: beautiful.  I like the looks of that library.  My biggest concern was really the quantity of items but this library certainly would have made my job easier.