# Looking for recommendations for a shopping cart control with paypal connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I am looking for a nice control that allows me to have a shopping cart on my webpage.

Requirements:
- Easy to implement. I want to add items into the cart from everywhere. Like

```
mycart.Add(new CartItem("Name", "Description", Price"))
```

- Implemented shopping cart overview with the ability to delete previous added items.
- Allows connection to Paypal

Can anybody recommend such a control?

(I've already found [Looking for a lightweight ASP.net shopping cart that is PayPal compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522832/looking-for-a-lightweight-asp-net-shopping-cart-that-is-paypal-compatible) but the posted solution "shopping cart .net" does not seem to fulfill the third requirement, If I'm not mistaken.)

Comment: It says it has 'Paypal Pro API WCF integration', not sure what you mean by 'connection' to PayPal though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It decided to build my custom shopping cart and used a paypal component. I've decided to stick to [Spicelogic Paypal component](http://www.spicelogic.com/Products/ASP-NET-PayPal-Control-for-Website-Payments-Standard-4)

Answer (score 1):

SpiceLogic ASP.NET PayPal Control for Website Payments Standard is a collection of PayPal Buttons like BuyNow Button, Donation Button etc and one of the button is 'Upload Complete Card Button'. Yes, that 'Upload Complete Cart Button' will allow you to use code like this (if you are using ASP.NET MVC):

[image]

If you are using ASP.NET Web Form, you will even get better Design Time support as follows:

[image]

You can find the details from their page at : https://www.spicelogic.com/Products/ASP-NET-PayPal-Control-for-Website-Payments-Standard-4

Answer (score 0):

Do you want just a component that provides cart functions and its database? Do you need out of the box UI? I'm just confused because it seems that you already have a website.

Comment: I thought I would be able to use a shopping component that also has build in shopping cart functionaly as a asp.net control and paypal integration. After searching for hours I decided to write my own shoppingcart and just look for a paypal component